# Running NUnit tests written in C# with Jenkins on Linux

Tags: c#, jenkins, nunit

Is it possible to run tests (written in C# with NUnit) with Jenkins on Linux OS?

I can find a lot of info on running NUnit tests with Jenkins but can't find any speak of my situation.

**UPDATE**

Looks like it's [possible](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Hooks-to-execute-windows-dll-and-exe-builds-tp3400504p3400853.html). I'll need to use a Master Jenkins in Linux to run a Slave Jenkins in Windows. Described in the [article](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service).

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, what errors are you getting? Providing a little more detail into you issue may help you find assistance here. In my experience, if you haven't tried it and can't provide more detail the question may get closed as "not a question." http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @Frito, I have not tried building the server and installing Jenkins yet because I'd rather to make sure it's possible first. And my research hasn't help me to answer that question so I'm asking here.

Comment: Yes, its possible. (Most things are with enough time and effort.)

Comment: +1 for posting a solution you found! @Jodrell, I completely agree with the "most things" statement.

Comment: It may even be possible to run NUnit against Mono on a linux OS but I'd be tempted to take the slave approach first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's [possible](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Hooks-to-execute-windows-dll-and-exe-builds-tp3400504p3400853.html). I'll need to use a Master Jenkins in Linux to run a Slave Jenkins in Windows. Described in the [article](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service).

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be relatively painless using mono on Linux

1) Install NUnit Console.

sudo apt-get install monodevelop-nunit

2) Under Build in your Jenkins project "Add build step" "Execute shell" after your MSBuild step

```
cd "$WORKSPACE"
# so nunit does not fail on file operations
export MONO_IOMAP=all
nunit-console ./UnitTests/UnitTests.csproj
```

The only problem I ran into were failing tests involving NancyFx due to Nancy trying to access the projects bin/Debug directory.  (The project runs normally with mono under the same environment setup)  This turned out not to be a problem as we moved away from Nancy.